# Instantiating classes inside array declaration

Tags: php, arrays, class

I apologize, I have dabbled with some PHP, but never done anything serious until now.

Basically, I have something like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    function _construct($var1, $var2)
    {
        //property assignments
    }
}

function doStuff($array)
{
    //do stuff to $array
}

$myArray = array();
$myVar1 = "foo";
$myVar2 = "bar";
$myVar3 = "test"
$myVar4 = "aaaaa"
//etc...
```

What I want to do is create an instance of `MyClass` and store it into `$myArray`.  I know I can do the following:

```
$classInstance = new MyClass($myVar1, $myVar2);
$myArray[] = $classInstance
$anotherInstance = new MyClass($myVar3, $myVar4);
$myArray[] = $anotherInstance
//etc...
```

This process will be done multiple times (with no loops) sequentially.  Once I have done this multiple times, I will be doing the following:

```
doStuff($myArray);
```

Inside this function, I will be looping through with a `foreach`, etc.  This is going to be tedious.  What I want to know, is there some way that I can do something like (I know this isn't proper syntax):

```
$myArray[] = new MyClass($myVar1, $myVar2);
$myArray[] = new MyClass($myVar3, $myVar4);
//etc...

doStuff($myArray);
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Actually, `$myArray[] = new MyClass($myVar1, $myVar2);` is perfectly valid.

Comment: Why `$myArray[] = new MyClass($myVar1, $myVar2);` isn't proper syntax ?

Comment: Oh, thanks.  I didn't realize it was proper syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax `$myArray[] = new MyClass($myVar3, $myVar4);` is valid already. You can do exactly as you want to:

```
$arr = array();
$arr[] = new stdClass;
$arr[] = new stdClass;
$arr[] = new stdClass;
$arr[] = new stdClass;
$arr[] = new stdClass;

var_dump($arr);
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (0) {
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (0) {
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (0) {
  }
  [3]=>
  object(stdClass)#4 (0) {
  }
  [4]=>
  object(stdClass)#5 (0) {
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys for your help.  I didn't know you could do that.  More reason why I'm really beginning to like PHP.

Answer (score 0):

```
$myArray = array(
    new MyClass('foo', 'bar'),
    new MyClass('test', 'aaaaa')
);
```